# KVM error under MX Linux 21 after upgrade

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm

I got KVM error after hardware upgrade upgrade (more RAM and changed MB with same model from another computer (got 2 equal) due to broken ports). It worked as a charm, now I got error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 65, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 101, in tmpcb
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/libvirtobject.py", line 57, in newfn
    ret = fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/domain.py", line 1329, in startup
    self._backend.create()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 1353, in create
    raise libvirtError('virDomainCreate() failed')
libvirt.libvirtError: unsupported configuration: Domain requires KVM, but it is not available. Check that virtualization is enabled in the host BIOS, and host configuration is setup to load the kvm modules.
```

What I did until now:

1. Checked if KVM is properly installed - Yes
2. Checked BIOS for "virtualization - turn -ON"
3. I have try to make everything I got in internet, but still same error message.
4. I have try to reinstall KVM and run, but no success.

Information about the machine [here](https://pastebin.com/0a7UZVPZ)

Comment: tell us more about `Checked BIOS for "virtualization - turn -ON"` what did you do

Comment: Also, the latest BIOS for that motherboard is A09 - of course if A06 was on the old motherboard then no need to update

Comment: And finally, what's the output of `lsmod | grep kvm`